# SFTP Account for specific folder

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So we're hosting using Google Cloud and I need to create a specific SFTP account using normal username and password for a specific folder. I prefer not to use SSH keys as this is for non tech people and the directory is rather isolated from the rest of the server.
I don't seem to find much information regarding this, perhaps someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

SFTP (SSH file transfer protocol) is a protocol that provides file transfer and manipulation capabilities. It can work over any reliable data stream, but is typically used with SSH.

Open sshd_config file.

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the Line containing “PasswordAuthentication” parameter and change its value from “no” to “yes“

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Now, restart the “sshd” service using the following command.

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: if you really want do like that then i think you will have to jailroot them